# How to add a Co-Administrator in the new Azure portal?

Tags: azure, portal

For adding a co-administrator the [Howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456328) refers to a "Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN" view. But I can't find anything like this in the new portal.

Does anyone know how to do this in the new portal? Is there a way to login to the old portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want go to old portal just click in bottom to "Preview" (green button) and press "take me to previous portal"

[image: too old portal]

Answer (score 12):

The "classic" portal (manage.windowsazure.com) has been retired. Co-admins are managed through the portal.azure.com site now. To manage co-administrators:

1. Go to Subscriptons from the main nav
2. Select the subscription you want to manage
3. Go to Access control (IAM)
4. Find the user you want to add/remove as co-administrator
5. Click the ellipsis on the right
6. You should see the option to add/remove co-administrator (whichever one is applicable)

Comment: There are no ellipsis on the right if I try this... Are there any prerequisites to see them? (The official MS document (that also mentions right-click) mentions something helpful like "f you do not see the Add as co-administrator option, refresh the page or try another Internet browser." which browser are you using where this works?

Comment: I believe you have to be a co-administrator to see them (or the account/service administrator). Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator#add-or-change-co-administrator) to a MSFT document that has more information.

Comment: Well as what I want to do is add myself as co-administrator I cannot already be one. I am owner and want to add my owner user as a co-admin for backwarts compatibility (add certificate to license) I know that guide but right click does not work in my portal and the ellipsis you mention is missing as well. Does this still work for you? Did you create the user/subscription at a time where the old portal was still active? I also have an old subscription created before the close of the old portal where i have the ellipsis and everything is fine but not for the new one

Comment: I believe only the service administrator and other co-administrators can add/remove co-administrators. An owner isn't sufficient to perform the operation, which is why you can't see the ellipse option.

Comment: That's very interesting. I was told by my support that owner rights should be sufficient for this. Guess they did not really know what they were talking about.

Comment: I urge you to verify what I said. I should have been more explicit, but I started my answer with "I believe...".

Comment: I want to add a hotmail.com email Id as co-admin to my azure subscription.Bu the add button is not getting enabled after I enter another users hotmail id. Not sure what to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you need to use the old portal to administrate co-admins. You can access the old portal at windows.azure.com. Once you are there and have signed in with your Live Id, select the Hosted Services category (bottom left) and then the User Management subcategory (top left).

Comment: David - You need to hang out here more often. There is way too much knowledge in that head for 96 rep on SO.

Comment: Hmm, I no matter what I do I always end up in the new portal.

Answer (score 2):

in the Azure portal, you need to goto subscriptions, select the subscription, then select Access Control (IAM).  Add a person with the owner role, then click the ellipsis and select add as co-administrator

**IMPORTANT** You have to make someone an owner before you can add them as co-administrator
[image]

Comment: I don't see the ellipsis at the end.  I'm the account administrator and one of the owners in the list gets "You need to be the account administrator to settle the outstanding balance".  Which tab is this - role assignments?

Comment: Ok, it seems to have changed.  Now you click on Add in the top row and "Add co-administrator" is one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the new Portal for this, you can click the "SETTINGS" option in the Left navigation bar and select the "ADMINISTRATORS" tab in the top. You also can manage certificates as well in this option.

Comment: Sure enough, in time, this has become the old portal, but it remains the only way to effect this.  In the new portal, you'd have to add it using the RBAC feature.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Portal as of May 2023 has changed slightly. Instead of the ellipsis, the +Add button has an option to add a co-administrator. Slightly updated instructions for 2023:

1. Go to Subscriptons from the main nav
2. Select the subscription you want to manage
3. Go to Access control (IAM)
4. Choose +Add
5. Choose Add co-administrator
6. Search and select the user from the Select user dialog on the right
7. Click Add

Answer (score -1):

With current portal go to :

1. Azure Active Directory
2. Roles & Administration
3. From the list of roles click the role you want to give the new person
4. You will be on a page where there is a button **add member** click that button to add the person(the person must already be added/created in the active directory as a user)
5. On the right side in the field type the person name(email used to add her/him) and click **select** (A button under the field.

That's all.